# How to generate a 64-bit two's-complement integer given the low bits and high bits?

Tags: javascript, python, bit-manipulation

Given that javascript cannot hold 64 bit integers, sometimes it represents them as a dictionary with the following three keys:

```
{ 
  low:-1547376220,
  high: -1,
  unsigned: false
}
```

I have a service using javascript that generates this dictionary. I have another service written in python that receives this data and wants to create the 64 bit number from it. Is there any way to do this in python? Maybe a library that does this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a signed result, you can use:

```
(high << 32) | (low & 0xffffffff)
```

For an unsigned result, you can use:

```
((high & 0xffffffff) << 32) | (low & 0xffffffff)
```